# Is there a way to disable resizing and dragging of events for on specific views on React Big Calendar with drag and drop add on?

Tags: react-big-calendar

I can't see anything in the API docs that would allow for disabling the resizing/drag and drop events on particular views.

For example, if I want to disable the ability to drag/drop and resize events only on the month view but keep the functionality in the day view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by:

- Tracking the view state of the calendar by using the `onView` event and setting state when the view is changed.
- Assigning the `resizeableAccessor` and `draggableAccessor` a function that resolves to false if the current view is set to "month"

```
    const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState(DEFAULT_VIEW);

    <DnDCalendar
          resizableAccessor={() => currentView !== 'month'}
          draggableAccessor={() = > currentView !== 'month'}
          onView={view => setCurrentView(view)}
          ...
     />
```

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm! I think you can make this the accepted answer.